# Auto Tagging Customers in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I can't seem to find any documentation on whether it's possible to use either Liquid or the Shopify API to assign tags to logged in customers.

I know that I can manually add tags to existing customers, but I'm really hoping there's a more efficient way of going about it - such as creating a button/link that would assign a specific customer tag to a logged in customer's customer profile when they click on it - let them tag themselves, so to speak.

I know there's the `{% assign %}` function in Liquid, but that one doesn't seem to be capable of affecting variables such as `{{ customer.tags }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems easy enough. If a customer choose to tag themselves, send the tags to your App, where you can use the API to update the customer tags. You can use Ajax for that. Checking the console out... I quickly set some tags on a customer, assuming call arrived with the tags, it all worked.

```
c = Customer.first
=> #<ShopifyAPI::Customer:0x000001012dafa8 @attributes={"accepts_marketing"=>true, "created_at"=>"2012-06-08T22:15:47-04:00", "email"=>"ding@dong.com", "first_name"=>"d", "id"=>92898480, "last_name"=>"dong", "last_order_id"=>nil, "note"=>nil, "orders_count"=>0, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"0.00", "updated_at"=>"2012-06-08T22:21:22-04:00", "tags"=>"", "last_order_name"=>nil, "addresses"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::Address:0x000001012d77b8 @attributes={"address1"=>"1330 14th Street", "address2"=>"", "city"=>"Santa Monica", "company"=>"dong incorporated", "country"=>"Canada", "first_name"=>"d", "id"=>128540200, "last_name"=>"dong", "phone"=>"3103950840", "province"=>"", "zip"=>"90404", "name"=>"d dong", "province_code"=>nil, "country_code"=>"CA", "default"=>true}, prefix_options{}, persistedfalse]}, prefix_options{}, persistedtrue

>> c.tags = "Holy Roller, Vagrant Snafu"
=> "Holy Roller, Vagrant Snafu"
>> c.save!
=> true
>> c = Customer.first
=> #<ShopifyAPI::Customer:0x00000101339968 @attributes={"accepts_marketing"=>true, "created_at"=>"2012-06-08T22:15:47-04:00", "email"=>"ding@dong.com", "first_name"=>"d", "id"=>92898480, "last_name"=>"dong", "last_order_id"=>nil, "note"=>nil, "orders_count"=>0, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"0.00", "updated_at"=>"2012-09-13T14:23:39-04:00", "tags"=>"Holy Roller, Vagrant Snafu", "last_order_name"=>nil, "addresses"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::Address:0x000001013372d0 @attributes={"address1"=>"1330 14th Street", "address2"=>"", "city"=>"Santa Monica", "company"=>"dong incorporated", "country"=>"Canada", "first_name"=>"d", "id"=>128540200, "last_name"=>"dong", "phone"=>"3103950840", "province"=>"", "zip"=>"90404", "name"=>"d dong", "province_code"=>nil, "country_code"=>"CA", "default"=>true}, prefix_options{}, persistedfalse]}, prefix_options{}, persistedtrue
>> c.tags
=> "Holy Roller, Vagrant Snafu"
```

So it seems you could set up something pretty quickly to let customers tag themselves.

Comment: I can see the logic behind your approach, but lack the technical skills to implement it.

When I said beginner, I meant "knows enough HTML5/CSS2/CSS3/jQuery/Liquid to get by". Wouldn't even know where to start with what you've got posted there . Would you happen to have any links to guides that I should read up on so that I might figure out how to implement your example in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try the e-book I wrote here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Developer_Handbook but note that it is not a how-to programming guide.

Comment: So... I have to use AJAX to collect the customer's ID number and the name of the tags to be added, then write an app that uses that collected information in conjunction with the API to update the customer tags?

Comment: Yes, that is one certain way to go. There are probably others, but I came up with this one first, so I go with my gut instinct.